# Split_part not giving full data in redshift sql query

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

i have table with below data:

```
account_id app_name.   triggered_signatures
aaaa        bbbb       111,222,333
aaaa        bbbb       111,222,444
yyyy        xxxx       111,222,444
yyyy        xxxx       111,222,555
```

the expected result are:

```
account_id app_name.   triggered_signatures cnt
aaaa        bbbb       111                   2
aaaa        bbbb       222                   2
aaaa        bbbb       333                   1
aaaa        bbbb       444                   1
yyyy        xxxx       111                   2
yyyy        xxxx       222                   2
yyyy        xxxx       444                   1
yyyy        xxxx       555                   1
```

what i tried:

```
SELECT b.account_id, 
           b.app_name, 
           Split_part(triggered_signatures, ',', 1) as "triggered_signatures",   
           Count(DISTINCT b.event_id) AS cnt 
    FROM   "public"."bus_request" b 
    WHERE  b.date > Getdate() - 2 and b.date < Getdate() - 1
    gROUP  BY b.account_id, 
              b.app_name, 
              triggered_signatures
```

this giving me only the first string in the list and not the whole list when i have for example triggered_signatures = [a,b,c,d]
i get only a. how can i get the whole signatures.

Comment: . . That is what `split_part()` does and what it is documented to do.  If that is not what you want, then ask a question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: i edit the question

Comment: You have a bad, bad, bad data model and really should fix it.  It is bad to store numbers in strings.  It is bad to store multiple values.  If you are stuck with the data as is, you should communicate how bad the model is.  Is there a maximum number of values?  Or a list of valid values?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the maximum number of values, you can do:

```
select account_id, app_name, triggered_signature, 
from ((select b.account_id, b.app_name, b.event_id,
              split_part(triggered_signatures, ',', 1) as triggered_signature
       from "public"."bus_request" b 
       where b.date > Getdate() - 2 and b.date < Getdate() - 1
      ) union all
      (select b.account_id, b.app_name, b.event_id,
              split_part(triggered_signatures, ',', 2) as triggered_signature
       from "public"."bus_request" b 
       where b.date > Getdate() - 2 and b.date < Getdate() - 1
      ) union all
      (select b.account_id, b.app_name, b.event_id,
              split_part(triggered_signatures, ',', 3) as triggered_signature
       from "public"."bus_request" b 
       where b.date > Getdate() - 2 and b.date < Getdate() - 1
      )
     ) b
where triggered_signature is not null
group by b.account_id, b.app_name, b.triggered_signature;
```

Add more `union all` statements if you need to for all the values.